# Google Apps multiple domains in one account with mail

Tags: google-workspace, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does ghs.google.com CNAME work for Secondary Domains](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/does-ghs-google-com-cname-work-for-secondary-domains)

I have a Google Apps account, that has several domains (not aliases but domains). 
I only have `mail.domain.com` access on one of them. If I try to go and change it, I can only choose to have `www.google.com/mail/domain` where the domain is different from each domain, or I can choose to have `mail.domain.com` but then it is only my primary domain that will be the destination for all my domains and I don't want that. I want:

`mail.domain.com`
`mail.domain2.com`
`mail.domain3.com`

I have set up all MX records and all that it's just that when I try to access `mail.domain2.com` and `mail.domain3.com` I get an error from Google saying:

> 404. That’s an error. The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Is it impossible to hook up GApps this way?

Comment: do you want all the other domains to resolve to `mail.domain.com`? so if i send an email to `gary@mail.domain2.com` it will send to `gary@mail.domain.com` instead?

Comment: or do you want separate divisions, with different domains, under one account?

Comment: I have this same problem like many others. see my question here for a workaround: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/does-ghs-google-com-cname-work-for-secondary-domains

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem should be answered via this link： http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=182452

Google Apps treats add-on domain as a sub-organization than an independent firm whatever it's set as alias or separate domain.

Regarding this, I think you have to register Google Apps separately for each domain.

Also, I think there is a way you can check if you're able to do what you want, take a look at your Google Apps Dashboard, if there's only your primary domain core service listed, I think that means you can't tweak other add-on domains to use address like mail.domain2.com...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295

What you need to do is go to the administrative panel, click "Domain settings" then "Domain names" then click "Add a domain or a domain alias"

Then you should click "Add another domain"

Enter the domain....

BOOM! WORKS! :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry if my question has been vaguely formulated. I have added domain2 and domain3 as other domains, and I can send to somemail@domain2.com, the problem is that when I try to access mail.domain2.com or mail.domain3.com I get an error from google, I can access mail.domain.com, but not the others.

Comment: is `domain2.com` supposed to forward to `domain.com`?

Comment: No domain2 is simply domain2.com and domain is domain.com two seperate domains, owned by the same firm, but two different concepts

Comment: What kind of error are you getting when you try to log in?

Comment: http://mail.xn--mngderabat-d6a.dk/